# files not beginning with a dot

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu

How do you delete all files not beginning with a dot by using wild-cards, instead of using grep and such commands.
I am a newbie in Unix and want to understand the basics.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Typically, files that begin with a dot are not included in wildcard matching, so just a "rm *" will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, .'s are not included - so you can just run

```
rm *
```

To verify you are about to delete the files rather than to act rashly - it may good idea to:

```
echo *
```

The reason for this - is that files that begin with a dot are considered to be 'hidden'. So they are immune to standard * operations. (To actually delete them - you need to specify in the command)